# CSS Z-index sliding images

Tags: css, z-index

I´ve a litle problem with a website.

> jn-racing.de

The "Banner" bar under the navigation in the background is an `.png` image with gras but the sliding images are in the front of the png.

Z-index of the sliding images are 3 and the css class "banner" are 99.

The background must be in front of the sliding images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The childs of #slider and #slider itself are positioned (relative), which means they belong each to their own stacking context and the z-index will have no effect.

A)

You'll need to remove the position-property. But that might conflict with your positioned images, so that's not really an option.

B)

You'll need the grass-background to reside in the same stacking context as #slider, which means is has to be on an element, which is a direct child of #banner too (a sibling to #slider).

Example:

```
#slider:after {
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    width: 1024px;
    background: url(images/banner.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your grass .png your html under the `#slider` div and give it (the new `img`) an ID. As long as it is a background, it will be harder to move it to the front via css. Does that help?

Comment: once you've done that, you should be able to position your grass on top of the sliding images.